# Open a fancybox when the hyperlinkfield of gridview is clicked

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview, fancybox

I have a Gridview that has Hyperlinkfield.When that field is clicked,I want a fancy box to open and in that fancy box I want an iframe to display the page that is hyperlinkfield has to open.

My Gridview is:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"DataKeyNames="SrNumber"
                    OnRowDataBound="GridView2_RowDataBound" 
                    Width="100%"
                    ShowFooter="false"
                    EnableViewState="false"
                    AutoPostBack="true">
                    <Columns>
      <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="SrNumber" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="newpage.aspx?SrNumber={0}" DataTextField="Note"  HeaderText=""/>
                   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Note" SortExpression="Note">
                   <ItemTemplate>
                       <a id="ahrefclick" class="forPopup"  href="newpage.aspx?SrNumber  <%#Eval("SrNumber")%>"><%#Eval("Note")%></a>
                   </ItemTemplate>
                   </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
```

Currently,There are only two columns and both are actually same.
the hyperlinkfiled is taking me to the next page. And I waa trying to add fancy box logic to the gridview using Template field.

the javascript code is:

```
 $("#ahrefclick").click(function (e) {

        $(".forPopupGrid").fancybox({
            'titlePosition': 'inside',
            'transitionIn': 'elastic',
            'transitionOut': 'none'
        });
    });
```

I am still not getting the pop up.I am new to the fancybox.Please help!

thank you!

Edit:
my jquery and fancybox links are:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="http://fancybox.net/js/fancybox-1.3.4/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <link href="http://fancybox.net/js/fancybox-1.3.4/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" rel="stylesheet"
        type="text/css" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try targeting the *class* of the actual link like this

```
$(".forPopup").fancybox({
   'titlePosition': 'inside',
   'transitionIn': 'elastic',
   'transitionOut': 'none',
   'type': 'iframe' //<-- if opening external pages
});
```

... you don't actually need the `click()` method (fancybox will be triggered once the selector is bound to it)

Comment: I changed the code according to your suggestion still the page opens in a new window and pop up does not show!

Comment: make sure your path to jQuery as well as fancybox js and css file are correct (and not returning a 404 error) ... or share a link to make it quicker ;)

Comment: I just edited my question and have added all the links to Jquery and fancybox.Can you please check and tell me if that is sufficient and correct?

Comment: the paths might be right but you may not have permission to access those files from your site so it may return a 403 Forbidden error. Try placing those files in your server and/or use firebug to check that the files were loaded properly. Also, I assume you are wrapping your fancybox code inside the `.ready()` method, aren't you?

Comment: i just changed the links and kept the files on my server.And I checked that files are getting loaded properly using the chorme's javascript debug console.yes the fancy box code is inside the .ready() method.Still the pop up does not show.

Comment: got a link to see the issue?

Comment: no.The application is not hosted anywhere right now.It is on my local server unfortunately.

Comment: my problem go solved! I re-read the fancybox documentation and i realised that I had not written 'type': 'iframe' !

Comment: If you are opening an external page, you may need set `type` to `iframe`; see my edited answer